# How to find the maximum of a csv file by addition

Tags: python

For a project, I have a csv file that contains such information years, states and a number of fires. I need for one question to add up every number of fires in years to find which is the one that had the most. I approached the problem with that code:

```
year,"state","month","number","date"
1998,"Acre","Janeiro",234,1998-01-01
1998,"Acre","Janeiro",7,1999-01-01
2000,"Acre","Janeiro",55,2000-01-01
2001,"Tocantins","Janeiro",45,2001-01-01
```

```py
import csv

file_amazon = open('amazon.txt', 'w')

with open('data.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    years = set()
    liste_addition = []
    maxi = 0
    worst_year = 0
    for row in reader:
        years.add(row['year'])
    for y in years:
        year_to_test = y
        if row['year'] == year_to_test:
          liste_addition = liste_addition.append(int(row['number'].replace('.', '')))
          is_it = sum(liste_addition)
    if is_it > maxi:
      worst_year = sum(liste_addition)

print (worst_year)
```

It doesn't work, saying `TypeError: NoneType object is not iterable (line 17)`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you share ① the full traceback of the error you're encountering, and ② example rows of `data.csv`? That way we can help you dissect where it's going wrong.

Comment: @j6m8 i have example, but the format when i post it here is confusing...

Comment: if you nest it in triple-backticks like your other code-block, stackoverflow will add horizontal scrollbars. way easier to know what data you're working with! but you could also just paste the header names, if that's easier done.

Comment: @j6m8 hope it's okay now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `collections.Counter` like below:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

with open('data.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    fires_per_year = Counter()
    for row in reader:
        fires_per_year[int(row['year'])] += int(row['number'])

print (fires_per_year.most_common(1))
```

Comment: Thank you turns out the other guy's replys wasn't right